# How to install build tools for v141_xp for VC 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I'm using the newest release of MSVC 2017 community with platform toolset v141, but I'd like the executables still work on XP, so I assume I need to use the v141_xp toolset, which however results in:

*Error MSB8020: The build tools for v141_xp (Platform Toolset = 'v141_xp') cannot be found. To build using the v141_xp build tools, please install v141_xp build tools. Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then selecting "Retarget solution".*

I didn't find anything like that in the MSVC installer. Any ideas?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I am not entirely clear on whether your issue is installing the C++ tools for Windows XP or modifying your project/solution to target that platform. Either way, the following [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/configuring-programs-for-windows-xp) should help you out.

Here is a summary on how to install the toolset:

- Bring up the Visual Studio installer (**Tools -> Get Tools and Features)**
- Select **Desktop development with C++**
- Select **Windows XP support for C++** from the **Summary** section
- Click **Modify**

[image]

[image]

Comment: The name of this has changed in VC 2019. Now it's: "C++ Windows XP Support for VS 2017 v141"

Comment: The current version of the VS2019 Preview installer I have only lists it under "Individual components" > "Compilers, build tools, and runtimes" > "C++ Windows XP Support for VS 2017 (v141) tools [Deprecated]". It is not listed on the "Workloads" page at all anymore.

Comment: If installing from command line the components to add are `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.WinXP` and `Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.NativeDesktop.WinXP`

Answer (score 18):

On Visual Studio 2019 this option is deprecated but you can still select it :)

Here is a summary on how to install the toolset:

- Bring up the Visual Studio installer (Tools -> Get Tools and Features)
- Select **Individual components**
- Select Windows XP support for C++ from the Summary section
- Click Modify

[image]

Comment: Also FYI, this option is still available with VS 2022 Preview 4. I've tried building my solution in VS 2017, VS 2019 and VS 2022. All build happily.

Comment: @Micdev42 be warned VS 2022 doesn't use an XP-compatible CRT. Some Vista+ implementations are used in the backend, like std::shared_mutex uses a SRWLock after [VS 2019 14.27 toolset version](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/configuring-programs-for-windows-xp?view=msvc-170#:~:text=version%20starting%20with-,14.27,-.%20If%20your%20Windows)... although it builds fine in XP compiler and targeting XP, built apps won't actually run on XP. And the thread-safety static init /Zc:threadSafeInit needs to be turned off, since it uses Vista+ tech; or static objs will be null with no ctor run.

Comment: VS 2022 doesn't ship v141_xp out of the box, yes. The toolset will still work if selected separately as shown above, and it's still officially available even in the latest installer (also of note that the other "v141" libraries/tools like MFC should still be compatible with it). As for `/Zc:threadSafeInit-` that was a bug that popped up with v140_xp and was [fixed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes-v15.0#c-libraries) with the next version.

Comment: Note that if planning on doing statically linked C++ binaries, you should make sure v141 is also installed when installing `v141_xp` - https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/VS-2022-VC-MFC-causes-v141_xp-applicat/10078503#T-N10105298 . The statically linked binaries generated by v141_xp without v141 toolset will call NT6 only APIs. C and dynamically linked CPP binaries seem to still work fine in XP without v141 installed alongside.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and the reason for that was a not needed VCTargetsPath system variable. After removing it, VS 2017 now sees V141 toolset.
I had VS 2017 Community first, maybe that made the problem.

Comment: Removing the VCTargetsPath system variable worked for me! Thank you!