# What is the latest C++ standard to target Windows XP with Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, windows-xp, crt

Visual Studio 2019 seems to have good support for C++17. Unfortunately, it seems binaries built with it require the Universal CRT to be installed on the target machine, and the minimum supported OS for the UCRT is Vista.

So, if I want to build a binary to target **Windows XP**, must I use a VS C++ compiler *preceding* the UCRT? Is that VS 2013, which has some support for C++11?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The latest toolset that has Windows XP support is **v141_xp**, that is the XP toolset from Visual Studio 2017. It has full **C++14** support, and *partial C++17* support.
It comes with Visual Studio 2019, too:

[image: VS 2019 installer with selected XP toolset]

Unfortunately, it does not have full C++17 and C++20 support.

The latest update of VS2019 has almost complete C++20 support in v142 toolset, and there is an update expected to make it complete, but it is without XP support.

VS2022 drops Vista and support some C++23 in its v143 toolset. It still ships with v141_xp toolset as optional [deprecated] component.

The v141_xp toolset still has the support of C++14, and partial C++17. It mostly corresponds to the [Conformance table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=msvc-160) where they mention VS 2017. (Say, you will have `std::any` or  terse `static_assert`, but won't be able to use `shared_mutex`, as it relies on Vista SRWLOCK)

See also: [How to install build tools for v141_xp for VC 2017?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49516896/2945027)

Comment: But there is VSRedist 2015-19 for Windows XP.

Comment: @PaulK. Was you able to find it?